# Parsing a list from FastAPI JSON List

Tags: python, json, api, fastapi

I am trying to pull together a time-series predictor, that runs of a REST API.

The GET request should send 6 values, and then receive a series of predicted values back. However when I try to parse the values from the API, I realised that it is a JSON list, and I cant actually use the individual values. Is there a way to be able to get the individual values? Or is there a better JSON dtype that I should be using?

My code is:

```
num_days = np.arange(0, 14, 1)  # the amount of days the model is required to predict for

app = FastAPI()  # initiate the API


@app.get("/predict")
async def predict(data: List[str] = Query(...)):  # input a list as a query from the GET request
    print(data)
    for i in num_days:
        xpred = data[-6:]
        print('xpred: %s' % xpred)
        yhat = model.predict(np.asarray([xpred]))
        print('Input: %s, Predicted: %.3f' % (xpred, yhat[0]))
        data.append(int(yhat))
    return(xpred)
```

The data param that the GET Call provides turns up as the following, rather than a normal list:

```
["'90','87','98','91','92','100'"]
```

I m new to JSON and APIs so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You should fix the response you're getting. Putting a bandage here by parsing isn't the right way.